# TypeError: Cannot read property 'pathname' of null

Tags: reactjs, next.js

UPDATE:
commenting out this part from _document does actually solve the problem, but why?

```
<Link href={`/search`} prefetch={false}>
                <a
                    className="d-inline-block text-center"
                    style={{ textDecoration: 'none', color: darkColor }}
                >
                    <Search
                        width="23px"
                        height="23px"
                        color={darkColor}
                        style={{ display: 'block', margin: '0 auto' }}
                    />
                    <div className="icon-lbl">
                        <span>search</span>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </Link>
```

I deployed a website to AWS yesterday, as usual, production and dev stages.
It kept failing at the production site but working fine on the dev site. although the same code.

Here's the only error that kept on repeating itself:

```
web-app_1  | TypeError: Cannot read property 'pathname' of null
web-app_1  |     at Link (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/link.js:159:14)
web-app_1  |     at processChild (/usr/src/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3043:14)
web-app_1  |     at resolve (/usr/src/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:2960:5)
web-app_1  |     at ReactDOMServerRenderer.render (/usr/src/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3435:22)
web-app_1  |     at ReactDOMServerRenderer.read (/usr/src/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3373:29)
web-app_1  |     at renderToStaticMarkup (/usr/src/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:4004:27)
web-app_1  |     at renderDocument (/usr/src/app/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/render.js:3:594)
web-app_1  |     at renderToHTML (/usr/src/app/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/render.js:47:72)
web-app_1  |     at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
web-app_1  |     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
web-app_1  |     at async /usr/src/app/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:71:285
web-app_1  |     at async /usr/src/app/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:70:142
web-app_1  |     at async DevServer.renderToHTMLWithComponents (/usr/src/app/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:92:300)
web-app_1  |     at async DevServer.renderToHTML (/usr/src/app/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:93:255)
web-app_1  |     at async DevServer.renderToHTML (/usr/src/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-dev-server.js:30:578)
web-app_1  |     at async DevServer.render (/usr/src/app/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:50:236)
web-app_1  |     at async Object.fn (/usr/src/app/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:35:306)
web-app_1  |     at async Router.execute (/usr/src/app/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/router.js:38:67)
web-app_1  |     at async DevServer.run (/usr/src/app/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:44:494)
web-app_1  |     at async DevServer.handleRequest (/usr/src/app/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:13:101)
```

What I tried is rollback to the previous version, and nothing changed unfortunately.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:
It seems like a popular issue among many nextjs developers. Probably because of the changes introduced in the latest versions. Check this PR:
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/15604

It should be live soon.

The problem can be solved by simply changing all Link items to plain anchor elements, like the following:

```
        <a
            className="d-inline-block text-center"
            style={{ textDecoration: 'none', color: darkColor }}
            href="/search"
        >
            <Search
                width="23px"
                height="23px"
                color={darkColor}
                style={{ display: 'block', margin: '0 auto' }}
            />
            <div className="icon-lbl">
                <span>search</span>
            </div>
        </a>
```

Please let me know if you ever find the cause behind this issue.

Comment: This isn't a fix, it's a workaround. I'm having the same error in my snapshots, but I have 100+ `<Link />` tags - I don't want to have to manually change them all

Comment: Right. It seems like a popular issue now among many nextjs developers. Check this PR: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/15604

Comment: Thanks for linking this :-) I ended up switching most <Link> to <a> for the sake a delivery, but it was painful. Hopefully this fixes it and I can safely revert those changes.

Comment: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/releases/tag/v9.5.1